# iOS Push - display message if app is active

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm implementing Push in a Xamarin Forms PCL project, and I'm having an issue with iOS.

If the user is actively using the app I want to display an alert to let them know they have received a notification and let them choose to View it (which changes the current page) or cancel.

If the app is not active, either in the background or not running, I want to go directly from the tap on the iOS notification to the notification page - no alert.  I have this working if the app is not running.

If the app is running, either in the background or active, the RecievedRemoteNotifications function is called which will display the alert.  I don't see a way in RecievedRemoteNotification to determine if the app was already active or if the user tapped the system-generated notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [ApplicationState](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/applicationState) property from `UIApplication.SharedApplication`.

More information about the possible values [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplicationState/). There is a `Background` state.